# Customize Sonata-admin dashboard "home"

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata, sonata-user-bundle

I'm quite new to the Sonata project, and as "playing" with it, I wanted to use it for one of my projects.

But there are a few questions that still remains for me about Sonata and the way it works and can be customized.

Here are they :

- Is it possible to use a custom controller to display the Dashboard
  "home"?
- I'd like to use roles and only roles to manage my security
  but can't figure out how to add Roles to the list that is displayed
  when you use the users creation form (by default located at
  `/admin/my/bundle/user/create`) under the "management" tab. Is it
  possible? 
  Screen to explain more : 
  [image]

  If yes, if anyone has hints about how to do this, they are welcome! :)
- Using this roles means managing the rights of these ones on my objects / controller. Is there any mechanism bundled for that or do I have to add mine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In symfony you can customize third party bundle by inheriting that bundle. So to use your own controller do the followings step by step:

In your custom bundle: `AcmeDemoBundle.php` add:

```
public function getParent()
{
    return 'SonataAdminBundle';
}
```

Now your bundle is inheriting `SonataAdminBundle`.

In your custom controller: `AcmeDemoBundleCustomController.php`

```
class CustomController extends CoreController {

  public function dashboardAction()
  {
      ...
      /* Here goes your code */
  }

}
```

Comment: This seems a good idea Turdaliev, do you have any ideas for the 2 other points?

Comment: I would suggest you `FOSUserBundle + SonataUserBundle` as user management tool.

Comment: Are you handling security by yourself. I mean without any third party bundle.

Comment: I'm also using the FosUserBundle + SonataUserBundle :) I would just like to figure out how to add roles to the list that is displayed when managing an user right. I've added it to the original post.

Comment: In `FOSUserBundle` you have `group` entity which is used to add new roles. Try

Comment: Yes but Group "aggregates" existing roles. I'd like to use roles directly to perform the "isGranted" operation on the user security token context, that's why I'd like to use directly roles and wonder how I could add / configure them.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42397/discussion-between-yoannch-and-turdaliev-nursultan)

Answer (score 2):

Turdaliev's answer is the correct way for your first question.

Regarding the roles, those displayed are those present in your application's security.yml file :

```
security:
    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH, ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_PAGE_EDIT, ROLE_SONATA_PAGE_ADMIN_BLOCK_EDIT]
```

In Sonata, an ACL mechanism is implemented, adding new roles for various actions such as view, delete, ... You may see a detailed example in the demo (https://github.com/sonata-project/sandbox), checkout the SonataAdmin security documentation for more details: http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/security.html

Comment: Thks for your help Hugo! I'm checking this out :)